# Good alternative to exec in python 2.7

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, dataframe, exec

I have code where I need to create pandas dataframe with the name from list. I know this can be achieved by using exec() function. But looks like its slowing down my app. Is there any better alternative to it ?

```
import pandas as pd
df_names = ["first","second","third"]
col_names = ['A','B','C']
for names in df_names:
    exec("%s=pd.DataFrame(columns=col_names)"%(names))
```

Answer (score 0):

Found below method and its working for me

```
import pandas as pd
df_names = ["first","second","third"]
col_names = ['A','B','C']
d={}
for names in df_names:
    d[names]=pd.DataFrame(columns=col_names)
```